# CATCHING URL FROM ROUTE // php laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```

Although I use these libraries, the input gives an error. Even if I add request or name input path to app.php in the config file, the problem is not resolved.

```
public function get_deneme(){
    $name=Input::get('name');
    $var="asd";
    return view('deneme')->with('var',$var);
}
```

ERROR: Input is underlined (Undefined type 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input'.)

NOTE : Laravel Framework 9.29.0

Comment: `Input::` was only available up to 4.2, or maybe something in the 5's. The proper way to get form requests now `request()->get('name')` or `request('name')`, or type hinting the request in the function definition. See https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#input

Comment: Also `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input` no longer exists as of Laravel 6, so remove that use statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As aynber mentioned in the comments Input was a very very old feature, since Laravel 5.2 you can use the following to get inputs

```
request()->get('name');
```

But since this still is not the best way to use the request, you can do it like this

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request

public function get_deneme(Request $request){
   $name = $request->name;
   $var = "asd";

   return view('deneme')->with('var',$var);
}
```